# UpdatePageContent with OneNote AddIns

Tags: onenote

Code Example:
I have a string pageContent as below:

```
<div class="ExternalClassB18B2CED421C4DBE9D35A9D59DB7749C">
    <table id="layoutsTable" style="width&#58;100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="vertical-align&#58;top;">
                <td style="width&#58;100%;">
                    <div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;">
                        <div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-multiline="true">
                            <p>Test Page</p>
                            <table width="100%" class="ms-rteTable-default" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width&#58;33.33%;">?ID</td>
                                        <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width&#58;33.33%;">?Task Name</td>
                                        <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width&#58;33.33%;">?Status</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="ms-rteTable-default">?1</td>
                                        <td class="ms-rteTable-default">?Task.1</td>
                                        <td class="ms-rteTable-default">?Completed</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <p>&#160;</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <span id="layoutsData" style="display&#58;none;">false,false,1</span>
</div>
```

Then I use method UpdatePageContent to update into OneNote
I try to debug and know that it can't parse to OneNote XML schemas.
I try a lot of of ways and can't find solutions for this case. Need Help !!!

Answer (score 1):

OneNote Object Model does support HTML, but you need to put it inside the HTMLBlock element. Simply wrap your HTML with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<one:Page ID="--yourpageid--" xmlns:one="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2010/onenote">
  <one:Outline>
    <one:OEChildren>
      <one:HTMLBlock>
        <one:Data>
          <![CDATA[
          html goes here
          ]]>
        </one:Data>
      </one:HTMLBlock>
    </one:OEChildren>
  </one:Outline>
</one:Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of HTML as your input, but the OneNote client add-in object model requires XML content formed in one of the OneNote XML schemae; it doesn't interpret HTML  (The OneNote service's REST API on the other hand does).

You could either switch to using the server-side API, or go through some process in your add-in to take the HTML and convert it to OneNote markup.